# Jquery Toggle input values

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle the values of two inputs when the user clicks a button
just like google maps does when you ask directions.

**HTML:**

```
<button>Swap</button>
<input type="text" value="Mountain View, CA 94043" disabled="">
<input type="text" value="Cupertino, CA 95014" disabled="">
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RmDesarrolloWeb/ng2f8L1v/1/)

Comment: If you only checked about any other example on internet, you could have made it. In my very particular opinion, we should use this when we can't get information or help on any other place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the old school swapping technique by using a temporary variable,

```
var inputs = $("input"),tmp;

$("button").click(function(){
 tmp = inputs[0].value;
 inputs[0].value = inputs[1].value;
 inputs[1].value = tmp;
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ng2f8L1v/2/)

I have used a common tag selectors here. If you have a firm identity for your elements in your original code base, use that to grab the required elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to study a lot guy!!!

JS:

```
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function (){
   var $first = document.getElementById("first");
   var $second = document.getElementById("second");
   var first = $first.value;
   var second = $second.value;
   $first.value = second;
   $second.value = first;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id='toggle'>Swap</button>
<input type="text" id='first' value="Mountain View, CA 94043" disabled="">
<input type="text" id='second' value="Cupertino, CA 95014" disabled="">
```

Comment: Thnks I´m a nooby in JS and Jquery i will study a lot this works too  :D